# C:/Windows log files write to C:/mylogs.txt

Tags: windows, cmd, logfiles

I have a little question for you :)
I want to write log files from C:/Windows to C:/mylogs.txt with ms-dos commands. But I don't know any ms-dos commands. How can I do this. Please help me !

Comment: 1: get DOS (if you can still get it from anywhere). 2: install it. 3: type `help` (if you want to use Windows Command Prompt, skip point 1 and 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only pretend to copy the content of Windows logs that are stored in the root folder of **C:\Windows**, then you could use the `Copy` command as follows:

```
Copy /B "%WinDir%\*.log" "C:\mylogs.txt"
```